# postfix, dovecot, roundcube adding email account

Tags: amazon-web-services, postfix-mta, dovecot, roundcube

I inherited a mail server setup with postfix, dovecot, roundcube setup on AWS. Virtual users stored in roundcube.

How do I add an email account? Do I add the account at roundcube db and it will automatically update postfix and dovecot or vice versa?

Greatly appreciate it as I have been trying a long time to add an email account without success.

Thank you in advance.
Richard

Answer (score 1):

You need to either add a virtual user or an actual user on the server. Everything depends on your existing setup. Under `nano /etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
```

Add the domain name(s) to `sudo nano /etc/postfix/vhosts`:

```
example.com
example.org
```

Then map the users to the drive location, `sudo nano /etc/postfix/vmaps`:

```
info@example.com      example.com/info/
rich@example.com      example.com/rich/
rlow@example.org      example.org/org/
```

Then run `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/vmaps` and `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`

Hopefully it helps.